# How can i apply Chebyshev's inequality to this case?

Tags: python, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have the a dataframe which includes heights. The data can not go below zero. That's why i can not use standard deviation as this data is not a normal distribution. I can not use 68-95-99.7 rule here because it fails in my case. Here is my dataframe, mean and SD.

```
0.77132064
0.02075195
0.63364823
0.74880388
0.49850701
0.22479665
0.19806286
0.76053071
0.16911084
0.08833981

Mean: 0.41138725956196015
Std: 0.2860541519582141
```

If I get 2 std, as you can see the number becomes negative.

```
-2 x std calculation = 0.41138725956196015 - 0.2860541519582141 x 2 = -0,160721044354468
```

I have tried using `percentile` and not satisfied with it to be honest. How can i apply Chebyshev's inequality to this problem? Here what i did so far:

```
np.polynomial.Chebyshev(df['Heights'])
```

But this returns numbers not a SD level i can measure. Or do you think Chebyshev is the best choice in my case?

Expected solution:

```
I am expecting to get a range like 75% next height will be between 0.40 - 0.43 etc.
```

**EDIT1: Added histogram**

To be more clear, I have added my real data's histogram

[image]

**EDIT2: Some values from real data**

```
Mean: 0.007041500928135767
Percentile 50: 0.0052000000000000934
Percentile 90: 0.015500000000000047
Std: 0.0063790857035425025
Var: 4.06873389299246e-05
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Modeling your data with a normal distribution might not be appropriate in your case. Take a look at the distribution offered here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html and pick one where the percentiles satisfy your requirements. Maybe the exponentially modified Normal?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What kind of data is that, from what physical phenomenon? Mathematics is just a tool: if you apply a model that has no physical meaning for your data, you'll get a result, but that result will have no physical meaning, either.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev these are height of grass :) I know that sounds funny. Actually they are divided by 10 as i am trying to keep them between 0 - 1. So what i am trying to predct is the height of grass in 3 months. Well it is not that important to be honest. The thing i am trying to figure out is: stats is stats. It should work with all type of numbers. Negative, positive (if it is not random). So that's why i am trying to findout how to use standard deviation with positive only integers (signed)

Comment: Not funny at all. That's a valid problem.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing two ideas from the same mathematician, [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev). These ideas are *not* the same.

[Chebysev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) states a fact that is true for many probability distributions. For two standard deviations, it states that three-fourths of the data items will lie within two standard deviations from the mean. As you state, for normal distributions about 19/20 of the items will lie in that interval, but Chebyshev's inequality is an absolute bound that is met by practically all distributions. The fact that your data values are never negative does not change the truth of the inequality; it just makes the actual proportion of values in the interval even larger, so the inequality is even more true (in a sense).

[Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) do not involve statistics, but are simply a series (or two series) of polynomials, commonly used in calculating approximations for computer functions. That is what `np.polynomial.Chebyshev` involves, and therefore does not seem useful to you at all.

So calculate Chebyshev's inequality yourself. There is no need for a special function for that, since it is so easy (this is Python 3 code):

```
def Chebyshev_inequality(num_std_deviations):
    return 1 - 1 / num_std_deviations**2
```

You can change that to handle the case where `k <= 1` but the idea is obvious.

In your particular case: the inequality says that at least 3/4, or 75%, of the data items will lie within 2 standard deviations of the mean, which means more than `0.41138725956196015 - 2 * 0.2860541519582141` and less than than `0.41138725956196015 + 2 * 0.2860541519582141` (note the different signs), which simplifies to the interval

```
[-0.16072104435446805, 0.9834955634783884]
```

In your data, 100% of your data values are in that interval, so Chebyshev's inequality was correct (of course).

Now, if your goal is to *predict* or *estimate* where a certain percentile is, Chebyshev's inequality does not help much. It is an absolute lower bound, so it gives one limit to a percentile. For example, by what we did above we know that the 12.5'th percentile is at or above `-0.16072104435446805` and the 87.5'th percentile is at or below `0.9834955634783884`. Those facts are true but are probably not what you want. If you want an *estimate* that is closer to the actual percentile, this is not the way to go. The 68-95-99.7 rule is an estimate--the actual locations may be higher or lower, but if the distribution is normal than the estimate will not be far off. Chebyshev's inequality does not do that kind of estimate.

If you want to estimate the 12.5'th and 87.5'th percentiles (showing where 75 percent of all the population will fall) you should calculate those percentiles of your sample and use those values. If you don't know more details about the kind of distribution you have, I don't see any better way. There are reasons why normal distributions are so popular!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry i because i am confused. But my data must be over zero. So they have to be positive. That will sound funny but they are heights of grass and i am trying to predict next bunch of grass heights from seeds :)

Comment: May i ask how did you find these numbers? -0.16 and 0.98?

Comment: @DonCoder: I'll add a few more comments in my answer.

Comment: I have edited and added the histogram of my real-data to my question. So you can see that data can not be below zero but zero.

Comment: @DonCoder: I do not understand your emphasis on your data all being positive. The question in your title asked how to apply Chebyshev's Inequality to your data. That inequality results in a negative number for the lower bound, but *it is completely accurate* and is the best that Chebyshev's Inequality can do. You later asked "do you think Chebyshev is the best choice in my case?" You later added more information about your problem, and the clear answer is *no*. Eric Zhou and I both gave you another method you could use.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the boundaries for the middle 75% of your data.

The middle 75% of the data is between the 12.5th percentile and the 87.5th percentile, so you can use the [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) function to get the values at the locations:

```
[df['Heights'].quantile(0.5 - 0.75/2), df['Heights'].quantile(0.5 + 0.75/2)]
#[0.09843618875, 0.75906485625]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [What does it mean when the standard deviation is higher than the mean? What does that tell you about the data? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-the-standard-deviation-is-higher-than-the-mean-What-does-that-tell-you-about-the-data), SD is a measure of "spread" and mean is a measure of "position". As you can see, these are more or less independent things. Now, if all your samples are positive, SD cannot be greater than the mean [because of the way it's calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation), but 2 or 3 SDs very well can.

So, basically, SD being roughly equal to the mean means that your data are all over the place.

Now, a random variable that's strictly positive indeed [cannot be normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals,_usually_[0,%E2%88%9E)). But for a rough estimation, seeing that you still have a bell shape, we can pretend it is and still use SD as a rough measure of the spread (though, since 2 and 3 SD can go into negatives, they lack any physical meaning here whatsoever and so are unusable for the sake of our pretention):

---

E.g. to get a rough prediction of grass growth, you can still take the mean and apply whatever growth model you're using to it -- that will get the new, prospective mean. Then applying the same to *mean±SD* will give an idea of the new SD.

This is very rough, of course. But to get any better, you'll have to [somehow check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) which distribution you're dealing with and use its peak and spread characteristics instead of mean and SD. And in any case, your prediction will not be any better than your growth model -- studies of which are anything but conclusive judging by e.g. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1365-3040.2005.01490.x (not a single formula there).